# How interface works in this code?

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to understand how interfaces work. I have read basic interface tutorials online and watched a few videos so i do have a good idea of what a interface is and its advantages. However i came across this piece of code that is utilizing interface feature and am having trouble getting my head around some of it. So i needed someone to just breakdown what exactly is happening. I will also write down what i understand of it so far so if i am wrong you can correct me.

Here is the Code.

**Bank Account Class**

```
package Interface;

public class BankAccount implements Measurable {
    private double balance;

    public BankAccount() {
        balance = 0;
    }

    public BankAccount(double initialBalance) {
        balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        double newBalance = balance + amount;
        balance = newBalance;
    }

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        double newBalance = balance - amount;
        balance = newBalance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public double getMeasure() {
        return balance;
    }
}
```

**Coin Class**

```
package Interface;

public class Coin implements Measurable {
    private double value;
    private String name;

    public Coin(double aValue, String aName) {
        value = aValue;
        name = aName;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getMeasure() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Interface**

```
package Interface;

public interface Measurable {

    double getMeasure();

}
```

**Data Set Class**

```
package Interface;

public class DataSet {
    private double sum;
    private Measurable maximum;
    private int count;

    public DataSet() {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
        maximum = null;
    }

    public void add(Measurable x) {
        sum = sum + x.getMeasure();
        if (count == 0 || maximum.getMeasure() < x.getMeasure())
            maximum = x;
        count++;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        if (count == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return sum / count;
    }

    public Measurable getMaximum() {
        return maximum;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package Interface;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DataSet bankData = new DataSet();

        bankData.add(new BankAccount(100));
        bankData.add(new BankAccount(100000));
        bankData.add(new BankAccount(10));

        Measurable max = bankData.getMaximum();

        System.out.println("Maximum :" + max.getMeasure());

        DataSet coinData = new DataSet();

        coinData.add(new Coin(0.25, "Quarter"));
        coinData.add(new Coin(0.10, "Dime"));
        coinData.add(new Coin(0.05, "Nickel"));

        max = coinData.getMaximum();

        System.out.println("Maximum : " + max.getMeasure());

    }

}
```

**What i understand so far**

I completely understand the bank class, the coin class and the interface. My problem is i don't quite understand a few things in the DataSet Class. First of all i do not get 
the use of private `Measurable maximum;` My understanding is after the specifier you usually declare a variable type such as int or double but in this case its assigning a variable name to the interface.  I guess if someone can explain me this then it will help me clarify my understanding of the DataSet class methods like its add method where Measurable parameter is passed.

Lastly i have difficulty understanding the Test class. I don't get how  `bankData.add(new BankAccount(100));` quite works. From what i understand we created a new object of dataset type but i don't get how a new bankaccount object is being created inside it.

If someone can please help me clarify this it would really help me understand interfaces a lot better. i have looked at a lot of simple examples that show very basic code like a car interface with a few methods which are then implemented by specific cars. However those primitive examples don't really help one in understanding the true essence of a interface. I believe this example is more practical and it will help. I apologize if this question is poorly worded as i am new to this java.

Comment: The first, is something called [**program to an interface**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). About the last issue, it's the syntax to create an instance of a class. Remember that class are types, so you can declare a variable of type `SomeClass` like `private SomeClass variable = new SomeClass(...);`

Comment: It isn't related to your question, but floating point should **never** be used for monetary values because it leads to rounding errors. Better to use `BigDecimal` or a whole number of cents stored in a  `long`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, the code `private Measurable maximum;` is simply declaring a variable named `maximum` which is of type `Measurable`.  What this means is that any object whose class implements the `Measureable` interface can be assigned as a value for the variable.

To answer your second question, any time you see the **new** keyword, an object is being created, so when you see this:

```
   DataSet bankData = new DataSet();
   bankData.add(new BankAccount(100));
```

...the first line is creating a new `DataSet` object, and the second is running the `add()` method on that object, and passing in as an argument a new `BankAccount` object.

In this case, the new object hasn't been assigned to a variable in the `main` method, since we don't have any use for it apart from passing it in to the `BankAccount`.

### EDIT

So, regarding this bit of code:

```
    Measurable max = bankData.getMaximum();             // get the max being store by the bank data
    System.out.println("Maximum :" + max.getMeasure()); // run the appropriate getMeasure method, depending on the actual type of max
```

What's going on here is that we first want to get the maximum from the `bankData` object, and then run the `getMeasure()` method on it.  Note that the type of the `max` variable is `Measureable`, just like the type of the argument to the `add()` method above it.

When we are adding `Measureable`s to our bank data, we don't know the true type, just that it's some class which has implemented the appropriate interface:

```
public void add(Measurable x) {
    sum = sum + x.getMeasure();
    if (count == 0 || maximum.getMeasure() < x.getMeasure())
        maximum = x;  // here maximum gets set to the object passed in, but we don't know its type at this point
    count++;
}
```

When we get `max` out of our `bankData`, we can run `getMeasure()` on it, even though we don't know the type of the object at compile time (this is something referred to as **polymorphism**).

Depending on the actual type of the object, the appropriate `getMeasure()` method will be called.  In this case, since we `add()`ed `BankAccount`s, then `BankAccount`'s method will get called.  But if we had added `Coin`s instead, then the `getMeasure()` method of the `Coin` class would have been called.

Comment: okay and also wondering about  Measurable max = bankData.getMaximum(); why is that called first and then max.getMeasure is printed

Comment: The first is to get the Measurable, the second is to print out its value.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. @azurefrog.

Answer (score 1):

First question:

In terms of variables and parameters, an interface can be used like any other class. Think of an interface an a contract. Declaring a variable of the interface type is like saying "whatever is in this pointer will fulfill this contract". You don't really care if it is a coin or a bank account, as long as it fulfills the Measurable interface.

Second question:

```
bankData.add(new BankAccount(100));
```

is similar to

```
BankAccount newAccount=new BankAccount(100);
bankData.add(newAccount);
```

now lets add the implict cast

```
BankAccount newAccount=new BankAccount(100);
Mesurable bankAccountAsMeasurable = (Mesuarable)newAccount;
bankData.add(bankAccountAsMeasurable);
```

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Yes that helps clear it up a lot i upvoted you could only accept one answer so i accepted the earlier answer.